# In react-native TextInput box show a line, how to removed it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

MY React-native APP I make a Input box but I get a line in Input box... How can I remove it?

```
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
  <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({editTodoVal: text})} value={this.state.editTodoVal}/>
</View>
```

**Style:**

```
inputContainer: {
        marginTop: 5,
        padding: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
 input: {
        height: 40,
        padding: 4,
        marginRight: 5,
        flex: 6,
        fontSize: 18,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#fff',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 1,
        color: '#000',
    },
```

**Please check my Images for more seance:** 
[image: Hare my input box show Line]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default it comes with underline, if you need to remove then use : `underlineColorAndroid='transparent'` . Also check [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) for more information.

Comment: @jigar_shah Thanks it's working but What about the **IOS**.

Comment: I think it there would not be any issue with IOS.